# How/where to install Nvidia nccl2 to a specific directory, in order to run XGBoost with multi-GPU suppport?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I need to install Nvidia's nccl2 library to a specific directory in order to run XGBoost with GPU support. How do I install the nccl library while designating the directory to build/save, and where is the appropriate directory or default directory?

The library can be downloaded as a .deb from nvidia [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nccl), you will need an Nvidia developer membership. The Github is [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl).

The [XGBooost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support) has build instructions:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DUSE_NCCL=ON -DNCCL_ROOT=/path/to/nccl2
make -j4
```

So I would need to know in advance the path to the nccl2 installation (unclear if they mean the nccl.h file or the folder).